# Loading formatted data from text file in an object

Tags: java, oop, text, ascii

I would like to read a text file with the following format:

```
title1, 2010, isbn, 121212
author1, firstname, lastname
author2, firstname, lastname

title2, 1999, isbn, 565656
author1, firstname, lastname

title3, 2001, isbn, 898989
author1, firstname, lastname
author2, firstname, lastname
author3, firstname, lastname
```

What is the best way to load each data in object(s) using an object-oriented programming language like Java ?

Do I have to create one class wich the attributes are title, year, isbn and authors like this:

```
public class Book {

    private String title;
    private String year;
    private String isbn;
    private List<String> author; // A list because I don't know how many authors wrote the book
}
```

or multiples classes, one for each entity:

```
public class Book {

    private String title;
    private String year;
    private String isbn;
}

public class Author {

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: This will be downvoted. What did you try so far?

Comment: What if firstname or lastname have a comma?

Comment: write java code to open the file, read line by line, split the line and store relevant data into Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your "formatted" file really formatted? You will run into problems because there are two types of objects in your file. And they are not recognizable from a parser perspective. This means that you will need custom logic where you analyze what you parse, and then need to decide what object it is and how to store it.

One approach for this could be http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/ 
Your file looks like a csv file to me and could be parsed as such.

If you have control of your formatted data, you should change it to make it clearer what the purpose it is. You'd have a few options, for example:

1. Separate into 2 CSV files
   You could have 1 file for books, another for authors. The opencsv lib above will then automatically parse your files into Java objects for you that you can use.
2. Create a json format for your file

for example, instead of formatting it like above, you can use:

```
{
 "title" : "mytitle",
 "year": 2001,
 "isbn" : 1231312,
 "authors" : [ "author1", "author2" ]
} ...
```

This format will enable you to use GSON or Jackson object mappers to parse those files, at which point it becomes very easy. Google will have plenty of examples on how to use that.

Hope that helps,

artur

Comment: Thank you pandaadb, but unfortunately I have no control of this file. So I can't reformat it.

Comment: In that case Chronos answer would be fine for you. In terms of your objects, I think it is good practice to separate Book and Author. Book can then contain a list of authors for you. Or an author can contain a list of books or both (this depends on what your application wants to do).

Answer (score 0):

Here's all the pieces you should need to put together a solution.

To read a file line by line use a [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html):

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( filename ) );
```

Now you can read a line by calling, for example

```
String line = reader.readLine();
```

To split the line into its comma separated elements you could use [String.split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-). eg.

```
String[] token = line.split( "," );
```

You should be able to put together a solution using these tools and some creativity :)